# Error in implementing SVM

Tags: numpy, machine-learning, computer-vision, svm

Here is my code for cats and dogs image recognition:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split


filename= 'catdog_datasets.txt'
filename1= 'catdog_datasets.txt'
raw_data = open(filename, 'rt')
raw_data1 = open(filename1, 'rt')
#data = numpy.loadtxt(raw_data,dtype='object',delimiter=":")
features_data = np.loadtxt(raw_data,dtype='object',delimiter=":",usecols=(0))
labels_data = np.loadtxt(raw_data1,dtype='object',delimiter=":",usecols=(1))
print(features_data.shape)
print(labels_data.shape)

#print(labels_data)
#print(features_data)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(features_data,labels_data,test_size=0.2)
print (y_train.shape)
print (y_test.shape)
print (X_train.shape)
print (X_test.shape)


clf = SVC(kernel='linear',C=1.0)
clf.fit(X_train,y_train)
predictions = clf.predict(X_test)
```

The catdog_datsets.txt contains the HOG feature vectors of 500 images each of cat and dog, with label assign as 0 for cat & 1 for dog.The file format is:
0.270150 0.070257 0.040265 0.037243 0.013678 :0

Note: The feature vector is of size around 1765*1 just for the sake asking the question I have given size as 5*1.The problem is that the feature vector is a string,I want to convert it into an array of float to provide to the SVM.This the error I am getting:

```
clf.fit(X_train,y_train)
  File "C:\Users\TIKA-OPT790-04\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\svm\base.py", line 149, in fit
    X, y = check_X_y(X, y, dtype=np.float64, order='C', accept_sparse='csr')
  File "C:\Users\TIKA-OPT790-04\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 573, in check_X_y
    ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
  File "C:\Users\TIKA-OPT790-04\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 433, in check_array
    array = np.array(array, dtype=dtype, order=order, copy=copy)
ValueError: could not convert string to float:0.270150 0.070257 0.040265 0.037243 0.013678
```

Comment: Please show some samples of your data. Some lines from both your files. Are you sure you are reading the data correct?

Comment: Both the files contain the same data,the file size is very large.It contains features vectors,then followed by the delimiter ":" then label "0" or "1".

Comment: The data is like this: f1 f2 f3 f4 ............................................f1565 :0 for a single image (i.e the first line )the feature vectors are separated by space character.Each image is represented by a vector of size 1565*1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is because your file has lines like :

```
f1 f2 f3 f4 ............................................f1565 :0
```

As you observed, the features are separated by a white space, and the whole feature vector is separated from label by a colon (:).

Now in your code, you are using `delimiter=":"` so your `features_data` will only contain single value for each line like this:

```
f1 f2 f3 f4 ............................................f1565
```

You need to split that too into multiple features to use it correctly.

Now `numpy.loadtxt` dont support multiple delimiters nativerly so you have to use other options or workaround.

1. Split the `features_data` after you have done in your current program:

   ```
   features_data = np.array([l.strip().split(' ') for l in features_data])
   ```
2. Recommended: Use [`pandas.read_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

   ```
   all_data = pd.read_csv(raw_data, sep=':|\s+', engine='python', header=None)

   # All but last column
   features_data = all_data.iloc[:,0:-1]

   #last column
   labels_data = all_data.iloc[:,-1]
   ```

Comment: Yes you are correct,the feature_data is like this:'f1 f2 f3 ....... f1565' for each line,As far as I know it should be converted it into am array of float like this [f1,f2,f3,..........f1565],then only it can fed into the SVM??

Comment: using this: features_data = np.array([l.split(' ') for l in features_data]),I get data in  this format:[ list(['f1','f2','f3'............'f1565', ' ']

Comment: Aah yes. Thats because of last space in your string. Please check the modified answer.

Comment: No, I am getting feature_data as an array of strings like this: [ list(['f1','f2'...'f1565'])]...........As far as I know that SVM understand only numbers,It shud be converted into array of folats like this:[ [f1 f2....f1565],[f1 f2 ....f1565]................................]???????

Comment: When I am trying this,features_data = features_data.astype(np.float) , I get an error:  features_data = features_data.astype(np.float)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

Comment: @sultan How about using this: `features_data = np.array([l.strip().split(' ') for l in features_data], dtype=np.float)` For actual float data, this returns a 2-d array and not list as you said. Are you sure that there are only floats in your data? If still experiencing problem, try second solution.

Comment: Getting the same error: features_data = np.array([l.strip().split(' ') for l in features_data], dtype=np.float)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.Yes the file contains only float data,I can send you the data if you want.

Comment: @sultan Yes please do so. You can upload it on google drive and give me the link

Comment: Please find link :https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bx4fkiQf7CZb9S43ayPBKE1glQfqxco1/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @sultan The first line of your file contains '0.2630.270150' which is not a valid float. Please correct that and use the command I sent in the above comment. It should work.

Comment: It worked but now every feature vector value is considered singular not as an array and  not getting any output.I think this is probably due to the x_train size of (800,1764) instead of (800, ) and also X_test size of(200,1764) instead of (200, ).

Comment: But do you understand that SVC needs a 2-d X and 1-d `y`. So the output is current. The dimension of (800,1764) has 800 samples with 1764 features each sample. So its correct. Please add more details on how its not giving any output.

Comment: When I am working with large amount of datasets(around 25000 images),I am getting memory error.   features_data = np.array([l.strip().split(' ') for l in features_data],dtype =np.float)
MemoryError.I went through sparse matrices but was unable to find the solution.Please help.